# Ngrok error with stripe webhook: 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, ngrok

So I have setup a stripe webhook with ngrok but for some reason when the webhook is triggered it shows this error in ngrok, but in stripe dashboard it shows that the webhook was successfull, but it doesn't do the stuff that it's supposed to do when it's successfull.

[image]

I have been trying to fix this problem for a week now but found no error in my code, ngrok or stripe so I am asking for help here.

here is my code for the webhook.

```js
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), async (req, res) => {
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']
    let event

    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, stripeWebhookSecret)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`)
        return
    }

    switch (event.type) {
        case 'checkout.session.completed':
            console.log('success')

            break
        default:
            console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`)
    }
    
    res.send()
})
```

here is how I expose my local server host to internet with ngrok

[image]

here is how I setup the webhook with stripe

[image]

Comment: Your configuration looks mostly correct. The only thing I’d point out is not sure how ngrok handles `https://` requests vs `http://` requests. AFAIK ngrok also spins up an `http://` endpoint. Have you tried using `http` URL as webhook endpoint and see if it causes the same behavior?

Comment: @hanzo I cannot use http because stripe only lets me use https

Comment: are you sure? because I just tested it on my account and I can register a `http` webhook.